# Eclipse import dialog missing "General" folder--how to restore?

Tags: eclipse

I'm trying to import an existing project into Eclipse.  Instructions everywhere say to use "File | Import... | General | Existing Project".  Sounds great, but in my Eclipse there is no "General" folder in the Import dialog.  This is a customized Eclipse setup for work, so am assuming this option is disabled for some reason.  Is there an easy way to turn this back on?

Looked thru prefs dialog and saw nothing obvious.

Thanks!

Comment: You've also looked under all of the available categories in the import dialog?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure which plugin supplies the "General" folder in the import dialog. Check that org.eclipse.jdt is available. If JDT doesn't supply this entry, it depends on something which does, so installing JDT should solve the issue.

Comment: I do see org.eclipse.jdt in the list of installed plugins (via Help/About/Installation Details).

Comment: Export your preferences, exit Eclipse, rename workspace/.metadata to workspace/.metadata.bak, start Eclipse again, import prefs, import all projects again.